# Windows 8 opening two Chrome instances at login

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8

I switched from Windows 7 to Windows 8 with a fresh install. After install all my apps, every time that I log in into Windows two Chrome instances are launched. One is for the GTalk plugin but the other one opens a new Chrome window. This is annoying because sometimes the new window is opened after 3 minutes. How can avoid this to happen?

Comment: have you tried startup, msconfig...?

Comment: Try [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to perform in-depth analysis of each startup entry! [Run as Administrator]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the program from the startup programs list. Search for and open the task manager and click on 'More Details' and then the 'Startup' tab. Disable Google Chrome or the Gtalk plugin whichever one you don't want.

Comment: I had to disable both of them because they were in the same group but it's ok. Now the window doesn't appear at launch. Thank you.